# Pass Data From Shopify App To The Shopify Front-End

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am starting to create my first app using PHP laravel and osiset.

I have created a partner account and created an app as well. I have integrated the library also. Done with app installation and authorization.
Now I am stuck for the next step. I don't understand how can I link my code and settings implemented on my app to Shopify frontend. How can I link the app database to Shopify website?

I save all the customized data in the app and how can I link that data with Shopify website?

I am able to make a standalone app with PHP but don't understand how its data can be linked to Shopify website. How my app database can be used in shopify website?

I am new here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two main choices in 2022.

1. App Proxy
2. Theme App Extension

Also, Post-Purchase extensions, for checkout stuff, but I digress. You should have no trouble injecting your special content using #1 or #2.